# $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ closed under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ implies $S$ closed under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed w.r.t. $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$. Then $S$ contains all its limit points under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$, which means that if $\{x_n\}\subset S$ is a sequence converging to some point $x$, then $x\in S$. More precisely, $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $\lVert x_n - x \rVert_\infty<\varepsilon$.

Consider now a limit point $x$ of $S$, under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$. Then $x\in S$, with $\{x_n\}$ being a sequence entirely contained in $S$ and converging to $x$ under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$. Now, $\lVert x_n - x \rVert_2\le \lVert x_n - x \rVert_\infty=\sup\{\lVert x_n - x \rVert_2\}<\varepsilon$.

But now that's where I'm stuck. I think the next step should be something like this: suppose $x\not\in S$ under $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$. What is required to be shown in order to arrive at a contradiction? That is, to show that $x$ must be in $S$ under $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$.

Comment: On a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent, meaning they generate the same topology (that is, open sets in a norm are also open in the other norm, and similarly for closed sets). See, for instance, [this link](https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I would go about it like this:

$S$ is closed under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$ implies its complement $S^c$ is open.

For arbitrary $x\in S^c$ we can find an $\epsilon>0$ so that $S$ contains the open ball under $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$, which is $B_\infty(x,\epsilon)\subseteq S^c$

However, $\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty<\epsilon$ implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\lVert x-y\rVert_2\le\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty<\epsilon$

So $B_2(x,\epsilon\sqrt n)\subseteq B_\infty(x,\epsilon)\subseteq S^c$

So $S^c$ is open under Euclidean norm, so $S$ is closed under Euclidean norm.

Comment: I replaced it with $S^c$

Comment: When I just started reading your post, I stopped at the word mentioning complement of $S$ and devised a proof which is similar to yours, but I'm wondering if the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is actually needed here? Can we say that, since $\lVert x-y  \rVert_2 \leq \lVert x-y  \rVert_\infty < \epsilon$, $B_2(x, \epsilon)\subseteq B_\infty(x, \epsilon)$?

Comment: To prove $B_2(x,\epsilon)\subseteq B_\infty(x,\epsilon)$ one needs to take $y\in B_2(x,\epsilon)$, so $\lVert x-y\rVert_2<\epsilon$ and prove $\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty<\epsilon$, so you would need exactly the opposite of your inequality

Comment: But since we already know that $\lVert x-y \rVert_2 \le \lVert x-y \rVert_\infty$, we then know that $y\in B_2(x,\epsilon)\implies y\in B_\infty(x,\epsilon)$. Correct?
$$$$
Actually I didn't get where your $1/\sqrt{n}$ is coming from exactly.

Comment: $|x_i-y_i|\le \max_k|x_k-y_k|$ from where $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^2\le n(\max_k|x_k-y_k|)^2$, so $||x-y||_2\le\sqrt n \cdot ||x-y||_\infty$

Comment: Thanks. But isn't it true that if we know that $\lVert x-y\rVert_2\le \lVert x-y\rVert_\infty$, then it follows that $y\in B_2(x,\epsilon)\implies y\in B_\infty(x,\epsilon)$?

Comment: We do not know that $\lVert x-y\rVert_2\le\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty$ Take for example $x-y=(\epsilon,\epsilon,...,\epsilon)$ Then $\lVert x-y\rVert_2=\epsilon
\sqrt n$ but $\lVert x-y\rVert_\infty=\epsilon$

Comment: OK it makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a mistake: you claim that $B_2(x,\epsilon\sqrt n)\subseteq B_\infty(x,\epsilon)\subseteq S^c$, but it should be So $B_2(x,\epsilon\sqrt n)\subseteq B_\infty(x,\sqrt{n}\epsilon)\subseteq S^c$, so the proof falls apart.